# windows 7 web crystal report error (using dot matrix printer)

Tags: c#

If I use XP machine I can print directly web crystal report (windows internet explorer) perfectly using dot matrix printer (LX 300+ ii) but windows 7 machine cannot get perfect print same scenario. Some lines overwrite and lot of unwanted spaces printed.
I want know why is that..?